# How to create the repository (role is repository manager)with nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

i created a maven repository using nexus and upload the jars files.Same way how to upload the maven plugins to repository.i directly add the maven-complier-plugin,it is not working.it will gives some exception like org.apahce,parenet ,plexus ,codehaus required and org.apache.maven.lifecycle errors are geting..

i will not be maven central repository,only using commpany repository includes every in my repository jars and maven plug
plz help me i am first create the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a mirror in your settings.xml file?  If you want to force all users to use your repo and not repo1.maven.org, you'll need to enforce that.  Also, you probably want your nexus to proxy central so that any artifact you don't host will still be available once you setup the mirror to block all outside repos.